# Azure: Not able to trigger a release pipeline from another

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to create a hierarchy of pipelines in azure-devops with this folder structure (classic editor):

```
-Starter
-- Starter-Pipeline 1
-- Starter-Pipeline 2
-Master
-- Master-Pipeline 1
-- Master-Pipeline 2
```

Starter-Pipelines should trigger Master pipelines based on conditions. To achieve this I am using [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks).

`Name of the Build Definitions that shall be triggered: Master-Pipeline 1`

However, I am getting this error:
`##[error]Did not find any build definition with this name: Master-Pipeline 1`

Debug logs didn't help. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure: Not able to trigger a release pipeline from another

I could reproduce this issue when you trigger a **release pipeline** from another with the [Trigger Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&ssr=false#overview) Task.

That because **this task only support for Build pipeline Not release pipeline.**

Please check the description for this task:

> Build Task that can be used to trigger a **new Build** so that
>   build-chaining is possible. Supports as well conditional triggers.
>
> This build task enables the chaining of builds within TFS. It makes
>   use of the built-in TFS API to queue a new build of any **build
>   definition** (within the same Team Project or even across projects)
>   and has support for different conditions if the **Build** should be
>   triggered.

As test, I add a new **build** pipeline with name `Master-Pipeline 1`, then I could trigger that build pipeline in the release pipeline `Starter-Pipeline 1`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this explains my issue. How can I achieve the same for release pipeline?

Comment: Check this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=venzhyk.vnzk-vsts-tasks